# Is it possible to capture a specific CaseIterable enum

Tags: swift, generics, enums, type-alias

Is it possible to do the intent of this somehow? I want to capture an enum where its `rawValue` == `String` but also `CaseIterable`.

```
protocol StringCases: CaseIterable where AllCases.Type ==  String {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CaseIterable` doesn't have raw values. That's [RawRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable).

```swift
protocol StringCase: CaseIterable, RawRepresentable where RawValue == String { }
```

Also, each one is a "case", not a "cases", so leave off that "s"!